What is the source of "Ut avertam oculos meos ad intendum / intuendum"?
The quote "Ut avertam oculos meos ad intendum" or "... intuendum" can be found in several places on the internet, generally with a translation like "I close my eyes that I may see." It seems to be popular on T-shirts and user profiles.
However, the Latin doesn't match the given translation very well:

Ut avertam (oculos meos) would seem to make closing (averting) the eyes a clause of purpose or result, but the translation doesn't.
As far as I can tell, intendum is not a Latin word. Maybe
it's a variant of intendendum, the gerund of intendo? (I couldn't
find intendum in Perseus search, though.) If so, ad intendum could mean "in order to focus / understand."

The quote showed up as a suggestion for Latin study in our homeschooling community, so I'm trying to verify the correctness of it. But none of the instances I found online cite a source, so it's hard to verify. The closest matches I found were in the Vulgate:

Psalm 118:37 (119:37 in English translations): Averte oculos meos, ne videant vanitatem.
Isaiah 1:15 et cum extenderitis manus vestras avertam oculos meos a vobis

both of which are completely different in meaning.
My suspicion is that the quote is "dog Latin," or a mangled copy of an actual classical quote.
Any help in finding the source would be appreciated.
Update: Changed the question title to reflect the suggestion that the last word might be (supposed to be) intuendum.

It definitely doesn't mean 'I close my eyes that I may see,' for the reasons you cite, plus the fact that averting the eyes is hardly the same as closing them. I wonder whether the intendum is a corruption of intuendum, which would at least help put the word in the correct semantic field.

Follow-up: A search on the same phrase, but replacing intendum with intuendum, also turns up results, many claiming it has the same meaning. Needless to say, not one (as far as I can tell) offers any sort of attribution.

Interesting. So it does sound pretty likely that the original (or earlier) quote had intuendum, and it got changed by resemblance to "intend."

It could also be a misspelling of intentum. Somewhat idle musings, because it makes no sense either way. The sentence does not get that many Google hits actually, and the t-shirts are just generated images from print-on-demand companies – you get these for every dubious Latin quote; it's possible (and likely) that no such shirt has ever been made.

@SebastianKoppehel True. I guess it depends where your "notability threshold" is. But given that it showed up in teaching suggestions for a community, and is on so many tattoo sites that this PhD in Classical Studies called it out, I think it's worth looking for a source.
